# what is the main purpose of post() method of View

Tags: android

what is the main purpose of the post method which are associated with views such as imageview,textview etc.

```
new View(Context).post(runnable)
```

An example will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from the api document:

> Causes the Runnable to be added to the message queue. The runnable
>   will be run on the user interface thread. This method can be invoked
>   from outside of the UI thread only when this View is attached to a
>   window.

it look likes: if you want to update the view in *another thread*, you can simple using `post` method to update the view. Although the type is `runnable`, but **it can't run in a separated thread**, it will run in the ui thread just like invoke a normal method.

Comment: thank you for replying but what is it supposed to mean..you said its used to update the view in another thread but, it can't run in a separate thread and will run in the ui thread only...I am kinda confused with this...what is its purose then and in what scenarios should i apply this???

Comment: I think, if an API is called from another thread, after the response is obtained, we can update the view from the called thread using post method.